# How to use getopt when option is a string on C?

Tags: c, string, getopt

I'm working/developing a C program for my university, that can have 3 options when invoked (`-h` for help, `-o <argument>` (with or without it) and last option can be a string like(test-in-1):

```
./myprogram test-in-1
```

I have to process these options on my main, and do what's required when they are invoked. None of them are mandatory.

I was thinking in using `getopt` to parse the options however one of these options is actually a `string(char *)` and is with this one that I'm kinda lost since `getopt` is not able to read strings, only char or a char with an argument(for example,`-h`, `-o <argument>`, as far as I understood). Any idea of how can I do this?

I can't really post any code besides main line,since I'm at stuck at start of it `(int main(int argc, char *argv[]))`.

Thanks in advance for any advice/point in right direction.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691715/what-is-the-best-practice-for-creating-a-unix-linux-command-line-tool-in-c-c?lq=1)

Comment: thank you!! looks very easy to understand!

Comment: `test-in-1` isn't an option, it's a regular argument. `getopt()` and similar libraries normally only process options that begin with `-` (or `+` in `getopt_long()`). String arguments are left for the program to deal with by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a colon `:` which means it requires an argument and that argument will be set in `optarg`.

See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691715/what-is-the-best-practice-for-creating-a-unix-linux-command-line-tool-in-c-c/13691903#13691903)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, my problem is that the option is a string, not an argument of an option, that the tutorials around explains well. Or I'm completely wrong about getopt()?

Comment: @mario79 I linked another option which is getopt_long().

Answer (score 0):

If you're linking to the GNU C library, check out [getopt_long](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html).